# Simulated annealing and randomized hill climbing in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am looking to implement `simulated annealing` and `randomized hill climbing` for some function. I have been using scikit to for all ML algorithms/methods. I could not find this in scikit.

Could you suggest some python libraries using which I could test `simulated annealing` / `randomized hill climbing`? I could not find this, so therefore wanted to ask you guys here.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [ABAGAIL](https://github.com/pushkar/ABAGAIL) for simulated annealing and randomized hill climbing. The original source code is in Java but you can use in python with the bindings.
Example: https://github.com/pushkar/ABAGAIL/blob/master/jython/continuouspeaks.py